# Giving characterisation of non-degenerate $C^*$-representation.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $\pi: A \to B(H)$ be a representation on the Hilbert space $H$, that is $\pi$ is an algebra morphism that preserves the $^*$-operation.

I'm trying to show that the following two conditions are equivalent:

$$\forall \xi \in H\setminus \{0\}: \exists a \in A: \pi(a)\xi \neq 0$$
$$\iff$$
$$\overline{\operatorname{span}\{\pi(a)\xi: a \in A, \xi \in H\}}= H$$

I'm not able to show both implications. Hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: They aren't equivalent. Consider $A=\Bbb C$, $H$ some Hilbertspace of dimension $>1$ and $\pi: A\to B(H), z\mapsto z\Bbb1$. Clearly the first property holds, but the second doesn't.

Comment: @s.harp: the span of $\{z\xi:\ z\in\mathbb C,\ \xi\in H\}$ is $H$. You actually don't need neither the span nor all of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami oh I misunderstood the second property, I didn't see that $\xi$ varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to prove both contrapositives.

Define $$L=\overline{\operatorname{span}\{\pi(a)\xi: a \in A, \xi \in H\}}.$$

$\implies$: Suppose that $$L\subsetneq H.$$ If $\eta\in L^\perp$ is nonzero we have, for any $\xi\in H$ and any $a\in A$, 
$$\tag1
\langle \pi(a)\eta,\xi\rangle=\langle \eta,\pi(a^*)\xi\rangle=0.
$$
Thus $\pi(a)\eta=0$ for all $A$.

$\impliedby$: Suppose that there exists nonzero $\eta\in H$ such that $\pi(a)\eta=0$ for all $a\in A$. Again by the equality $(1)$, we have that $\eta\in L^\perp$, so $L\subsetneq H$.

Comment: Thanks. Very clear!